# How to get JSF2 working with Seam2

Tags: java, jsf, seam, jsf-2, seam2

Is it possible to get JSF2 working on the latest production Seam release (2.2.1.GA)?  I get this error on startup:

```
    javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Must have a Constructor that takes in a ComponentConfig
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$UserComponentHandlerFactory.<init>(AbstractTagLibrary.java:289)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary.addComponent(AbstractTagLibrary.java:519)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagLibraryImpl.putComponent(TagLibraryImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processComponent(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:569)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:361)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:314)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:263)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:535)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5193)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1933)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1605)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.maven.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jboss.seam.ui.handler.CommandButtonParameterComponentHandler.<init>(javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentConfig)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1674)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$UserComponentHandlerFactory.<init>(AbstractTagLibrary.java:287)
    ... 44 more
May 23, 2010 9:35:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: PWC1306: Startup of context /WalterJWhite-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT-Development failed due to previous errors
May 23, 2010 9:35:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: PWC1305: Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: PWC2769: Manager has not yet been started
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:892)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5383)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5211)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1933)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1605)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.maven.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
May 23, 2010 9:35:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.jboss.seam.ui.handler.CommandButtonParameterComponentHandler.<init>(javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentConfig)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5216)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1933)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1605)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.maven.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.jboss.seam.ui.handler.CommandButtonParameterComponentHandler.<init>(javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentConfig)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:354)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:535)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5193)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jboss.seam.ui.handler.CommandButtonParameterComponentHandler.<init>(javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentConfig)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1674)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$UserComponentHandlerFactory.<init>(AbstractTagLibrary.java:287)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary.addComponent(AbstractTagLibrary.java:519)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagLibraryImpl.putComponent(TagLibraryImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processComponent(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:569)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:361)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:314)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:263)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:337)
    ... 37 more
May 23, 2010 9:35:41 AM com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start
WARNING: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.jboss.seam.ui.handler.CommandButtonParameterComponentHandler.<init>(javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentConfig)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.jboss.seam.ui.handler.CommandButtonParameterComponentHandler.<init>(javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentConfig)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1933)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1605)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.maven.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
May 23, 2010 9:35:41 AM org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.jboss.seam.ui.handler.CommandButtonParameterComponentHandler.<init>(javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentConfig)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.maven.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
May 23, 2010 9:35:41 AM org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.jboss.seam.ui.handler.CommandButtonParameterComponentHandler.<init>(javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentConfig)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.maven.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
classLoader = WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)
SharedSecrets.getJavaNetAccess()=java.net.URLClassLoader$7@61b1acc3
```

Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should [supposedly](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/DoesSeamWorkWithJSF2) work. However, there might be some configuration issues with the type of Application Server you are using.

Also, I would use Seam 2.2.1.CR1 (latest) to get the best chance of it working

Comment: I am using the latest stable version of Seam and Glassfish v3.

Comment: Well according to Dan Allen there is a problem running Seam and JSF 2 with Glassfish V3: `I think that there may be an issue running Seam 2 on GlassFish V3, which is orthogonal to running Seam 2 applications with JSF 2.`

I think you should do as he suggests, to report problems on JIRA

Comment: Ok, I am really looking forward to Seam 3 and Java EE6.

Answer (score 4):

---

### HOW TO RUN SEAM 2 WITH JSF 2  - till Seam 2.3 comes out.

We're using Seam 2.2.2 and we simply cannot stomach the thought of using JSF1 any more now that JSF2 is available and provides some decent composite comp functionality. We can't adopt JEE6 yet like many of you so that leaves us in a bit of a temporary bind.

Instructions:

- download seam 2.2.X
- unzip JBOSS-SEAM-2.2.X.jar
- remove faces-config.xml from the jar and rezip. Use this jar instead of the shipped one.

most of the custom jsf class implementations overridden by the seam jar were implementing concepts that were pulled into JSF2 spec so you can just use the standard JSF2 implementations.

We are still using the seam navigationmanager though - but you don't have to.

heres a sample faces-config similar to the one in our app - you still need the seam resolver to hook into the seam el component namespace. forget the spring resolver if you are not using spring or are booting spring up through seam.

```
<application>
<navigation-handler>org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
<variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
<el-resolver>org.jboss.seam.el.SeamELResolver</el-resolver>
<message-bundle>org.jboss.seam.core.SeamResourceBundle</message-bundle>
</application>

<lifecycle>
<phase-listener>org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener</phase-listener>
<phase-listener>org.jboss.seam.document.DocumentStorePhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

the seam phaseliseners are required. the rest of the seam setup in web.xml is the same as before.

on startup jsf complains about two seam jsf components that arent JSF2 compatible, but we don't use and have never used them, so you can probably get around using them too.

other than that - i cannot find one thing which doesn't work - and we are doing a fairly advanced app.

also - make sure you use the latest EL impl so you can get method param passing etc - we're using 2.2.1-b05

Comment: By any chance, has your JSF2 application made use of any Ajax calls using <a:ajax /> or <f:ajax />?  I'm running into the issue I've documented in this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406636/seam-2-3-jsf-2-0-conversation-propagation-for-hselectonemenu and can't seem to find a solution to it

Answer (score 1):

You could run Seam with JSF2 provided you follow the following JIRA postings:

- https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBSEAM-4652
- https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBSEAM-4667

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that might just work.  I have a little bit of work to get stuff running again.